# Line cut in \tabularx{}

Tags: latex, beamer

I have a code below. I would like to remove the white space before the highlighted part.  [image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt,english,8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}


\title{Beamer Template}
\author{TeXstudio Team}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
        %\begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \scriptsize
        %\caption{Title }
        \label{tab:5}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
            {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
            }
            %\multicolumn{11}{@{}p{1\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
                %   Caption }\\
            \toprule 
            
            & Log Probability of Default & Log Recovery Rate
            & Log Spread & Log Leverage  \\ [0.5ex] 
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)  \\
            \midrule
            Log Damage 
            &0.017**    &-0.003***   & 0.002 & -0.157    \\
            &(0.0008)   &(0.003)   & (0.075) & (0.178)  \\
            Log Adaptation
            &-0.157***  &0.012  &-0.463** & 0.514*** \\
            &(0.021)    &(0.007)    &(0.182)    &(0.193)\\
            Log Damage X Log Adaptation
            &0.006  &0.018* &-0.398 &0.535 \\
            &(0.030) &(0.011) &(0.249) &(0.513)\\
            Constant
            &-1.227***&-0.117***&2.244***&0.101\\
            &(0.026)&(0.009)&(0.187)&(0.237)\\                      
            \midrule
            Observations &926 &925 &458 &177 \\
            $R^2$ &41\% &19\% &8\%  &38\%\\
            Adjusted $R^2$ &40\%&17\%&4\%&32\%\\
            Residual Std. Error 
            & 0.071 &   0.025 & 0.373 & 0.264 \\
            & (df = 907) & (df = 906) & (df = 439) & (df = 159)\\
            F Statistic 
            & 35.253*** &   11.455*** & 2.104***  & 5.811***  \\
            & (df = 18; 907)&   (df = 18; 906)& (df = 18; 439)& (df = 17; 159)\\
            
            
            \bottomrule 
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{0.8\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize \tiny{Note: *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01 }} \\
        \end{tabularx}
        %\end{table}
    \end{table}
    
\end{frame}

    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Log Damage X Log Adaptation` is too long to fit into a single cell. The easiest fix is to manually move the second part of the phrase into the next line.
- If you are using a `tabularx`, you should use at least one `X` column to make sure the table can adapt to the available space
- I would use `@{}` in front and after the other columns to get rid of the extra space
- To make reading the table easier, I would add some additional vertical space between the blocks
- Are you abusing the poor `X` as multiplication sign? Don't!
- the syntax `\tiny{...}` is wrong. It is a switch and does not take an argument. Use `{\tiny ...}` instead.
- Missing math mode around the `<` signs
- most of your table should be in math mode to get correct minus sign and proper spacing around operators, but I'm too lazy to add this in the example below...

```
 \documentclass[10pt,english,8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}


\title{Beamer Template}
\author{TeXstudio Team}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
        %\begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \scriptsize
        %\caption{Title }
        \label{tab:5}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
            {
                @{}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm}
                @{}
            }
            %\multicolumn{11}{@{}p{1\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
                %   Caption }\\
            \toprule 
            
            & Log Probability of Default & Log Recovery Rate
            & Log Spread & Log Leverage  \\ [0.5ex] 
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)  \\
            \midrule
            Log Damage 
            &0.017**    &-0.003***   & 0.002 & -0.157    \\
            &(0.0008)   &(0.003)   & (0.075) & (0.178)  \\\addlinespace
            Log Adaptation
            &-0.157***  &0.012  &-0.463** & 0.514*** \\
            &(0.021)    &(0.007)    &(0.182)    &(0.193)\\\addlinespace
            Log Damage $\times$ 
            &0.006  &0.018* &-0.398 &0.535 \\
            Log Adaptation &(0.030) &(0.011) &(0.249) &(0.513)\\\addlinespace
            Constant
            &-1.227***&-0.117***&2.244***&0.101\\
            &(0.026)&(0.009)&(0.187)&(0.237)\\                      
            \midrule
            Observations &926 &925 &458 &177 \\
            $R^2$ &41\% &19\% &8\%  &38\%\\
            Adjusted $R^2$ &40\%&17\%&4\%&32\%\\\addlinespace
            Residual Std. Error 
            & 0.071 &   0.025 & 0.373 & 0.264 \\
            & (df = 907) & (df = 906) & (df = 439) & (df = 159)\\\addlinespace
            F Statistic 
            & 35.253*** &   11.455*** & 2.104***  & 5.811***  \\
            & (df = 18; 907)&   (df = 18; 906)& (df = 18; 439)& (df = 17; 159)\\
            
            
            \bottomrule 
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{0.8\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize {\tiny Note: *$p<0.1$; **$p<0.05$; ***$p<0.01$ }} \\
        \end{tabularx}
        %\end{table}
    \end{table}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]